# Why do I get a malformed JSON in request body in this cURL call?

Tags: json, curl, dns, cloudflare

I have been trying to call the CloudFlare API v4, using an example provided in their own documentation.

This is the code of the example

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records/372e67954025e0ba6aaa6d586b9e0b59" \ -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \ -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ --data '{"id":"372e67954025e0ba6aaa6d586b9e0b59","type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"1.2.3.4","proxiable":true,"proxied":false,"ttl":120,"locked":false,"zone_id":"023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353","zone_name":"example.com","created_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","modified_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","data":{}}'
```

Which can also be found at
[Update DNS Records](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-dns-record-details)

Using Windows cmd.exe to run this command, I need to make it single line first, so I removed the "" and reformatted it (twice) making sure I altered no part in the process.

This is the same code in one line:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records/372e67954025e0ba6aaa6d586b9e0b59" -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"id":"372e67954025e0ba6aaa6d586b9e0b59","type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"1.2.3.4","proxiable":true,"proxied":false,"ttl":120,"locked":false,"zone_id":"023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353","zone_name":"example.com","created_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","modified_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","data":{}}'
```

When I run this single-liner in cmd, it works but I get a malformed JSON in request body, however, a visual check, formatting on Notepad++ and a run through the JSON validator are all positive, this JSON (copied from the CloudFlare documentation) is not malformed.

Error Message

> {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":6007,"message":"Malformed JSON in request body"}],"messages":[],"result":null}

Googling this error message or the error code gives me nothing and this same command works on a PC running Linux.

Can someone tell me if this is a known bug, if the JSON really is malformed or if something else comes to mind?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the answer in the blog post: ["Expecting to find valid JSON in request body..." curl for Windows](http://fendertech.blogspot.com/2014/09/expecting-to-find-valid-json-in-request.html).

For example, for [Purge everything](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-all-files) `--data` value will be:

```sh
# On Linux
--data '{"purge_everything":true}'

# On Windows
--data "{\"purge_everything\":true}"
```

For Windows:

1. Replace the single quotes with double quotes: `'` `-->` `"`
2. Escape the double quotes with a backslash: `"` `-->` `\"`

Comment: Yes replacing all single quotes with double quotes worked! Thanks @Veaceslav

Answer (score 1):

cmd.exe doesn't support single quotes, to run those commands straight from the docs you can use Bash.

Bash can be enabled in Windows 10 : https://www.laptopmag.com/uk/articles/use-bash-shell-windows-10

or Git Bash comes with Git for windows: https://gitforwindows.org/