# Wonder why trying to upload a Letsencrypt .pem certificate using cURL to Cloudflare API throws "Malformed JSON in request body" error?

Tags: api, ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a script that attempts to replace my site's SSL cert on Cloudflare. 
Certbot auto-renews the cert on the local server from Letsencrypt every three months. Now, the SSL .pem certificate renewed by certbot needs to be uploaded to Cloudflare using its API.

```
PRIVATE_KEY="/etc/letsencrypt/live/autoxxx.com.au/privkey.pem"

CERTIFICATE="/etc/letsencrypt/live/aautoxxx.com.au/cert.pem"

# read from files
PRIVATE_KEY=`cat $PRIVATE_KEY`
CERTIFICATE=`cat $CERTIFICATE`

DATA='{"private_key":"'$PRIVATE_KEY'","certificate":"'$CERTIFICATE'","bundle_method":"ubiquitous"}' 

curl -i \
     -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/rCWR4i3A24NZEzI4dFLYLAhU7tUBtJUSYQkh/custom_certificates/iqXVG2FV8Cgj5FXGMexIoJovtFQx5UhecVya" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: webdev@autoxxx.com.au" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: pg5Q89JI33nsgdA9iZwPky3q" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "$DATA" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

But, running this script throws the following error

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":6007,"message":"Malformed JSON in request body"}],"messages":[],"result":null}
```

Tried the quotes suggestion as in answer to the following question, but still the same error.

[Why do I get a malformed JSON in request body in this cURL call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806096/why-do-i-get-a-malformed-json-in-request-body-in-this-curl-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched Google extensively. 
Tried the following https://docs.vmware.com/en/Unified-Access-Gateway/3.0/com.vmware.access-point-30-deploy-config.doc/GUID-870AF51F-AB37-4D6C-B9F5-4BFEB18F11E9.html to put .pem into a single line. Used awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\n",$0;}' to achieve this, but now it threw "Invalid Certificate" response.

The following code works perfectly. The above awk command was replacing carriage returns with new line \n, but Cloudflare, apparently, wants the literal "\n".

```
PRIVATE_KEY="/etc/letsencrypt/live/autoxxx.com.au/privkey.pem"

CERTIFICATE="/etc/letsencrypt/live/aautoxxx.com.au/cert.pem"

# read from file, put the .pem into single line and replace carriage returns with the literal "\n"
PRIVATE_KEY=`awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\\n",$0;}' $PRIVATE_KEY`
CERTIFICATE=`awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\\n",$0;}' $CERTIFICATE`

DATA='{"private_key":"'$PRIVATE_KEY'","certificate":"'$CERTIFICATE'","bundle_method":"ubiquitous"}' 

curl -i \
     -X PATCH "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/rCWR4i3A24NZEzI4dFLYLAhU7tUBtJUSYQkh/custom_certificates/iqXVG2FV8Cgj5FXGMexIoJovtFQx5UhecVya" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: webdev@autoxxx.com.au" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: pg5Q89JI33nsgdA9iZwPky3q" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "$DATA" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```