# Can't post JSON data to GitHub API (and probably others)

Tags: json, http, raku, malformed

I'm using [`HTTP::UserAgent`](https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent) to try and use GitHub API from a program. Here's the program

```
use HTTP::UserAgent;

my $greeting = (%*ENV<BODY> ~~ /[Mm]erry/)??%*ENV<GREETING>!!%*ENV<HEY>;
my $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/raku-advent-calendar-article-2019/issues/%*ENV<ISSUE>/comments";
my %headers = Authorization => "token %*ENV<TOKEN>" ;
my %payload = body => $greeting;
my $agent = HTTP::UserAgent.new( useragent => "JJ's Xmas commenter" );
say $agent.post( $url, %payload,
                 Authorization => "token %*ENV<TOKEN>",
                 Content-Type  => "application/json" );
```

If the content-type is not established, there's a `malformed JSON` error. If it's used, however, the error is different: `422 Unprocessable Entity`. When using `curl` or similar, you can usually post directly the JSON string, but `post` in this case does not admit single strings, or if it's a form, I have no idea what to use as key. Can you please help?

Comment: When I [google for "malformed JSON"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22malformed+JSON%22) I get [an SO that may be what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806096/why-do-i-get-a-malformed-json-in-request-body-in-this-curl-call). When I [google for "422 Unprocessable Entity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22422+Unprocessable+Entity%22) the first result says "the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.", i.e. quite likely exactly the same cause.